# Play & JSON: How to make scala code more concise

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following `case class`...

```
case class Address(
  name: Option[String],
  zip: String,
  city: String
)
```

... I need to generate different JSON depending on whether or not `name` is defined:

```
val selector = address.name.map { addressName =>
  Json.obj(
    userId.key -> userId.value,
    "addresses.name" -> name,
    "$or" -> Json.arr(
      Json.obj(s"addresses.name" -> name),
      Json.obj("addresses.name" -> Json.obj("$ne" -> addressName))
    )
  )
} getOrElse {
  Json.obj(
    userId.key -> userId.value,
    "addresses.name" -> name
  )
}
```

If you look at the code above, both blocks have a common part:

```
Json.obj(
  userId.key -> userId.value,
  "addresses.name" -> name
```

Is there any way to make the code more concise without repeating the common part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods on `JsObject` you can use: [`++` or `+`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsObject). The first one merges with another JsObject, the second one adds a new field.

```
val commonPart = Json.obj(
  userId.key -> userId.value,
  "addresses.name" -> name
)
val selector = address.name.map { addressName =>
  commonPart + "$or" -> Json.arr(
    Json.obj(s"addresses.name" -> name),
    Json.obj("addresses.name" -> Json.obj("$ne" -> addressName))
  )
} getOrElse(commonPart)
```

Using foldLeft:

```
val selector = address.name.foldLeft(Json.obj(userId.key -> userId.value, "addresses.name" -> name)) {
  (commonPart, addressName) =>
    commonPart + ("$or" -> Json.arr(
      Json.obj(s"addresses.name" -> name),
      Json.obj("addresses.name" -> Json.obj("$ne" -> addressName))
    ))
}
```